# Tracking Android phone usage

Tags: applications, data-monitoring

My wife thinks I spend too much time on my smartphone, but I believe she spends more time than me on hers.

Is there a way to monitor and provide statistics on our phone usage, so we can objectively compare our smartphone addiction?

I don't want something too intrusive (I don't want anyone, including me, to be able to spy on my wife) or something which would require root access.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [QualityTime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime) meets your needs:

[image: QualityTime] [image: QualityTime] [image: QualityTime]
<sup>*QualityTime* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime); click images for larger variants)</sup>

> QualityTime is a fun, visually engaging and easy-to-use Android app that allows you to monitor and get real time reports on how much time you spend on your smartphone and on your favorite apps.

Comment: As you (Ben) wrote *I don't want me or a software editor to spy on my wife:* Please be aware that the app uses several analytics addons – a.o. *Flurry*, which may be quite intrusive (see: [Flurry: An Affront to Privacy](https://meghanclark.us/2014/04/flurry/)). It also wants to "edit your text messages (SMS or MMS)", "read your contacts" and "directly call phone numbers, send SMS messages" – which IMHO is not covered by the task it is intended for. So take care!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have the latest version of Android, so I can control the authorisations individually. I did not accept anything (except usage data access). I also did not login. That does not mean the app is not intrusive and sends the usage data to their servers though...

Comment: That and I blocked it with NetGuard :)

Comment: Good choice @Ben – I see I don't need to worry, you know how to nail it into its sandbox :)